# How to fetch specific json Field from woocommerce rest api

Tags: android, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I have fetched json data using woocommerce rest api from my wordpress'website and the response is like this :

```
[{"id":4077,"name":"Work Benches","slug":"work-benches","parent":4076,"description":"","display":"default","image":null,"menu_order":0,"count":10,"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories\/4077"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories"}],"up":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories\/4076"}]}},{"id":4802,"name":"Work Lights","slug":"work-lights","parent":4073,"description":"","display":"default","image":null,"menu_order":0,"count":23,"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories\/4802"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories"}],"up":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories\/4073"}]}},{"id":4029,"name":"Work Safety Protective Equipment","slug":"work-safety-protective-equipment","parent":0,"description":"","display":"default","image":null,"menu_order":0,"count":53,"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories\/4029"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories"}]}},{"id":5248,"name":"Yoga &amp; Pilates Blocks","slug":"yoga-pilates-blocks","parent":4296,"description":"","display":"default","image":null,"menu_order":0,"count":1,"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories\/5248"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories"}],"up":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories\/4296"}]}},{"id":4556,"name":"Yoga &amp; Pilates Mats","slug":"yoga-pilates-mats","parent":4296,"description":"","display":"default","image":null,"menu_order":0,"count":22,"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories\/4556"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories"}],"up":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.fynds.co.uk\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/categories\/4296"}]}}]
```

BUT what of i need just specific attributes like (id , name , slug) .

i have searched with many questions but no cleared answer , 
the purpose of reducing the incoming json data to make the application works faster 
**Uptate**
i have tried **Not** woocommerce rest api

```
https://*myweb*/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=10&fields=id,title
```

it worked 
But did not work with woocommerce rest api like this :

```
https://www.***/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=***&consumer_secret=****&per_page=10&field=id,name
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to only fetch the ```id, name, slug``` from the server end? Or you want a way to parse them in the app end?

Comment: yes i am looking to fetch (id , name , slug ) for example from server of course 
i already have handled the json response in android , but the problem is the result is very huge and the app become slow therefor i thought maybe id i reduce the incomming data will be faster any idea ?

Comment: you can not reduce the incoming data size until API stopped sending unused data. you can apply pagination if api supports.

Comment: but with this (https://*myweb*/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=10&fields=id,title) 
it should be something like it for woocommerce api

Comment: Though if you apply pagination then it doesn't have any effect of data size. Suppose you have 200 data each pagination 50 then 4 times API call will have occurred but you can not expect specific attribute until api stopped sending them

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a way, but you need to write a hook in `functions.php` in woocommerce ;)

Suppose the following URL `http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v3/products?fields=sku,name`

The trick is `fields` parameter, which has a comma separated list of fields that you what to retrieve.

So you hook this behavior in woocommerce... something like that:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', 'my_woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', 10, 3 );
function my_woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object( $response, $object, $request ) { 

    $data = $response->get_data();
    $newdata = [];
    foreach ( explode ( ",", $request['fields'] ) as $field ) {
        $newdata[$field] = $data[$field];
    }
    $response->set_data( $newdata );

    return $response;
}
```

and... *voila*

```
 {
    "sku": "544392",
    "name": "ACIDET 3 EN 1 GALON",
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v3/products/35809"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v3/products"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "sku": "544391",
    "name": "DESTAPADOR CANIERIA LEJIA GEL SELLO ROJOGL",
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v3/products/35808"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v3/products"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "sku": "544389",
    "name": "ACIDET 3 EN 1 950ML",
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v3/products/35807"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v3/products"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

...

Hope this help!! BTW I designed this solution reading in deep the source code.

:)

Answer (score 2):

I've added an IF to PazFernando code just in case you can send a get call without specifying the fields.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', 'my_woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', 10, 3 );

function my_woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object( $response, $object, $request ) 
{ 

   $data = $response->get_data();
   $newdata = [];

   if ($request['fields'] != null) 
   {
      foreach ( explode ( ",", $request['fields'] ) as $field ) 
      {
         $newdata[$field] = $data[$field];
      }
    
      $response->set_data( $newdata );
   }

   return $response;
}
```